# Nested Tables design doesn't work on print button in jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, nested-table

Nested table designs are shown as same in html template but the problem is when I click a print button then not show the nested table's correct design.
Here is my project test case link:https://jsfiddle.net/motalibhossaib/hfn8kd6c/1/

```
 <script>
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        colReorder: true,
        aoColumnDefs: [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': ['no-sort'] }
        ],
        "ordering": false,
        paging: false,
        info: false,
        searching: false,
        buttons: [
            'colvis',
            'excel',
            'print'
        ]
    });
```